# How can I launch an Android app from nfc with extra parameters?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

So here's the end goal that I'm looking for: I scan an nfc chip with my phone, it launches a timer that is set for X number of minutes.

Here is what I have so far:
I can launch an app with an NFC chip.

I can launch an app with an intent internally on my phone (using tasker) that launches `com.google.android.deskclock` and I can pass in the default time with `android.intent.extra.alarm.LENGTH`

So how can I launch an app from an NFC chip that has `android.intent.extra`... included?